# Python exec() bug

Tags: python, python-3.8

File1.py

```
from config import *
from jsundb import JsunDB
from fontchanger import fonter, symboler
from texts import *
from pyrogram import Client, filters

db = JsunDB(session_name, True, True)

bot = Client(session_name, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, phone_number=phone_number)

if not database.get_key('isrunned'):

    print('here database work nice')

    database.set_key('isrunned', True)

    database.set_key('lang', 'en')

    database.create_dict('mpa')

    database.set_dict_key('mpa', 'action', {'status': 'off', 'chats': [], 'type': 'typing'})

    database.set_dict_key('mpa', 'poker', {'status': 'off', 'chats': []})

    database.set_dict_key('mpa', 'markread', {'status': 'off', 'chats': []})


def get_lang():

    return database.get_key('lang')

def change_lang(lang):

    if database.get_key('lang') == lang:

        return 'already'

    else:

        database.set_key('lang', lang)

        return 'setted'

@bot.on_message(filters.me)

def self_messages_handler(client, message):

    if id := database.get_key('backup_channel'):

        pass

    else:

        database .set_key('backup_channel', str(client.create_channel('Self Bot Backups', 'Don\'t left this channel').id))


if 1==1:

    bot.run()
```

File2.py

```
imports

many functions

def Runner(filename):
    exec(open(filename, 'r').read())

Runner('File1.py')
```

I ran File2.py and it successfully run File1.py but when a telegram message arrived the function `self_message_handler` called and in function, python don't detected database variable or any variables and functions those are out of `self_message_handler` and I get `database  is not defined at line : if id := database.get_key('backup_channel'):` error

I use another idea : I wrote code in another file and then I ran another file in File2.py but It works only when we run File2.py with python and we can't create executable file from File2.py

so this Idea is BAD!

another idea that I had : write code with File2.py to another file and then `exec('import '+filename_without_py)`

but this Idea isn't good for me because I tested this idea and I don't get good result

Because those ideas results I should use exec() but how ? :(

Sorry for my BAD english -_-

Comment: why do you use `exec()` ? You should put code in functions and use `import File1` and `File1.function()` without `exec()`

Comment: @furas Can I delete File1 after importing and calling function?

Comment: why do you want to delete it ? If you delete it then you can't run it again. IF you don't want to have `File1` then put all code in `File2` - it will be simpler.

Comment: no I don't want run it again

Comment: @furas  Because my code is a python code encryptor and I don't want people can access created file

Comment: only code on web page can be safe - because people can't get it. Other code can be alwyas accessesed.

Comment: @furas But it can be harder :)))

Comment: @furas I use importing and calling function but it raise error for asyncio codes ```RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'```

Comment: you didn't show that you use `thread` and `async` in code - and `async` has to be run only in one thread. In other thread you have to create new `async` loop.